# css image crop resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I try to make i image gallery. But I have a problem. When the size of the images are different, the image can not be beautiful. so i need to add resize pictures.e.g.. The dimensions of the photo width: 800px height: 400px another photo's size 600px 1024px. I want to see my pictures size in a div width: 198px height: 198px. if 100% of the width 198px height dimensions are very different.

I want like facebook, whatever the size of uploaded photos. Picture without image size width: 198px height: 198px get. 
This is my demo : [CodePen](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/DecHI/)

**HTML :**

```
<div class="profile_cover_container">
  <div class="cover_container">
    <div class="cover_img">
      <a href="#"><div class="img_200px200px"><img src="https://scontent-b-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/t1.0-9/1780641_780166082011699_1924260798_n.jpg" width="198" height="198" padding="0"></a></div>
      <a href="#"><div class="img_200px200px"><img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t31.0-8/964870_679724332055875_989825665_o.jpg" width="198" height="auto" padding="0"></a></div>


      </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.profile_cover_container{
  position:relative;
  width:851px;
  height:400px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid #d8dbdf;

  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  margin-top:3px;
}
.cover_container {
  width:851px;
  height:400px;
  float:left; 
}
.cover_img {
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  height:400px; 
  background-color:#000;
}
.img_200px200px {
  float:left;
  width:198px;
  height:198px;
  margin:1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img_200px200px img {

   width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: Do you want this (http://codepen.io/petethepig/pen/dvFsA) or do you want to fill your container and cut the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want with pure css as you will need to make a calculation to see if the images height is less than the width.  As you have tagged this with jQuery, you can add the following css:

```
.img_200px200px img.height {
   width: auto;
   height:100%;
}
```

Then you can use this jQuery on document load

```
$('.img_200px200px img').each(function() {
    var image = $(this),
        height = image.height(),
        width = image.width();

    if (width > height) {
        image.addClass('height');
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MN2kM/1/)

Comment: thanks for reply.This script is beautiful. width is greater than height 198px 198px center of the picture only can we get?

Comment: @MustafaOzturk - this should center your images vertically and horizontally if they overflow the container: http://jsfiddle.net/MN2kM/5/

Comment: This works great too Mustafa. I thought you said "like Facebook"..but this looks good too. Good job @Pete

Comment: @Pete dear you use jquery.1.9.1.js . How can i entegrate in my website this script. I paste this code in head tag = <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> it will work. But when i download jquery-1.9.1.js then i can change <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> it will not working. What can i do in this section  ? can you help me please ?

Comment: when you add the script on your page can you browse to the file?

Comment: @Pete hi Pete can you help me please. I want to try this i think you can understand when you see my jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/T7arx/3/

Comment: hi try this - you need to put a `.` before class names in selectors and your images can't start with a width and height attribute - you need to set this using css:  http://jsfiddle.net/T7arx/4/

Answer (score 0):

Mustafa, I'm having trouble understanding what you really need, but I understand your english is not great. That's ok. Let me try this. I think this is what you are looking for. If not, let me know and I'll delete or modify the answer.

If you want to display all your pictures at 198px but you don't want the height to distort your picture proportionality, simply chage the height:to auto.

```
.img_200px200px {
    float:left;
    width:198px;
    height:auto;
    margin:1px;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

You may need to update your picture container as well.

Is this what you need?

******EDITED TO SHOW AN IMAGE******

You said "like facebook". Take a look at Facebook picture layout. They have a container that restricts the max-width so that it's never wider than 470px. But the height is auto to maintain proportionality. If you set a defined height to an image you may end up stretching it or compressing it.

Also, you want the width to be in percentages instead of pixels. That way when you resize the window, it can shrink with the browser as well

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply and sorry for my english  :) . If i change height:auto like height:198px image looking is not good. for example: you have 2 picture and also you create a div tag. Div width:198px; and height:198px; . All your picture in your div. first picture width: 500px; height:500px; picture looking in your div perfect. But another picture width:800px; height:400px; image not looking good in div.

Comment: It's cool man. We'll figure it out once we understand what you mean by "not looking good" what is your desired result? Can you give us a quick diagram made with Microsoft Paint or Powerpoint or something like that?

Comment: I'm updating my answer so that I can post a picture for you

Comment: ok i will create now I'm doing a screenshot.Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Can you check this picture  ?   https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t31/1888855_796585080369799_1058901885_o.jpg

Comment: also check this picture : 
https://scontent-a-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/t1.0-9/p261x260/1982252_796588173702823_1858830923_n.jpg

Comment: great! @Pete did it for you on the answer above. Thanks for the image that cleared things up.